# Group List of map based on a key in the best possible way (preferably using ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say i have a list of map like:

```
var x = [{"name":"Not1","type":"Email"},{"name":"Not2","type":"Instant"},{"name":"Not3","type":"Email"},{"name":"Not4","type":"Instant"}]
```

I want the output to be:

```
var result = {"Email":[{"name":"Not1","type":"Email"}, {"name":"Not3","type":"Email"}],"Instant":[{"name":"Not2","type":"Instant"}, {"name":"Not4","type":"Instant"}]}
```

How can i do it in the best possible way? thanks in advance

Comment: Use a loop. It's actually quite trivial, and there's no magic that really helps to simplify it further. Try it and show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do your stuff :

```
        let result = {};
        x.forEach((dataObj, index) => {
            result[dataObj['type']] = result[dataObj['type']] || [];
            result[dataObj['type']].push(dataObj);
        })
```

Comment: In ES6, you should be doing simply `for (let dataObj of x) {`

Comment: @Bergi Thats true when using for loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the `Array.prototype.reduce()` function;

```js
var x = [{"name":"Not1","type":"Email"},{"name":"Not2","type":"Instant"},{"name":"Not3","type":"Email"},{"name":"Not4","type":"Instant"}];

var output = x.reduce(function(accum, item, index) {
  
    if(accum[item.type] === undefined) {
        accum[item.type] = [];
    }
    accum[item.type].push({name: item.name, type: item.type});  

    return accum;
        
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a single line, with an empty object and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var x = [{ name: "Not1", type: "Email" }, { name: "Not2", type: "Instant" }, { name: "Not3", type: "Email" }, { name: "Not4", type: "Instant" }],
    result = x.reduce((r, a) => ((r[a.type] = r[a.type] || []).push(a), r), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```